# How you can say “Happy New Year” formally?

Tags: politeness, greetings

Good afternoon,

I have to send an e-mail to my future traineeship's menthor and I don't know how I can write to her today in a formal way a Happy New Year's greeting.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Happy New Year" is fine in both casual and formal contexts.

Comment: Often it is written with an exclamation point (Happy New Year!). I would.